# Python Gtk Grid removing all rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, grid, gtk, gtk3

I thought it would be easy for me, but I'm trying to remove all rows from Gtk.Grid (to populate it with new data of different length) and still have problems.
I tried like below, with row=0 or 1, changing row (row=row+1) or not changing row, because I don't know what do rows after removing one above, tried with '!=None' or without '!=None' and other options and still nothing:

```
row=0
while(self.grid.get_child_at(1,row)!=None):
    self.grid.remove_row(row)
    row=row+1
```

all I got was removing one row from grid.
I also tried to remove whole grid but it's problem when removing the widget before creating it (in the begining)

```
if (self.grid):
    {remove}
```

didn't work for me. I must add that the grid is populated (and I tried to remove it) not in main part of the program.

Comment: Have you tried to iterate over `get_children()` and remove everyone of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to display data use a `GtkTreeView`/`Store`. This is *made* for displaying data and scales well beyond 100 items.

The hacky approach:
Another option might be to just destroy the grid which in turn will destroy it's childen. But to be honest, this would just do the above loop implicitly. You could also wrap the above loop in a function and call that.

Comment: Thank You! GtkTreeview is in fact much better for my program, and clearing it is banal with ListStore.clear()

Answer (score 3):

```
    while True:
        if self.grid.get_child_at(0,1)!= None:
            self.grid.remove_row(1)
        else:
            break
```

Of course this will not work if you have children only in column 1 or bigger. You must search these too (self.grid.get_child_at(1,1), self.grid.get_child_at(2,1) etc).